# How to write the query in Entity Framewok for Stored procdure with multiple parameters

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, linq-to-entities, stored-functions

I am new to entity framework, and before I was use [BLToolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BLToolkit/) there I can use easily SQL stored procedure

```
public partial class AttendanceReport
    {
        public int AutoID { get; set; }
        public string StudentID { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public string Class { get; set; }
        public string Section { get; set; }
        public string MonthName { get; set; }
        public string TotalDaays { get; set; }
}
List<AttendanceReport> users = new List<AttendanceReport>();
                    {
                        using (DbManager db = new DbManager())
                        {
                            users = db

                                .SetSpCommand("SP_Att2Dates_Student",
                                db.Parameter("@StudentID", stid),
                                db.Parameter("@startDate", dateEdit_From.DateTime),
                                db.Parameter("@endDate", dateEdit_ToDate.DateTime))
                                .ExecuteList<AttendanceReport>();
                        }
                    }
```

Here AttendanceReport is the object and SP_Att2Dates_Student is Stored Procedure with three parameters.
now I am trying to write this in Entity Framework Query I have import stored procedures in Entities Model you can see in attached picture ====>[Stord Procedures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMcxj.png) now how can I write a query in

```
using (Entities db = new Entities())
                    {
                    var users = ????????????????????????????????   
                    }
```

Comment: Well, since you already have the function import you should be able to call it as a method of the context.

Comment: Do you have AttendanceReport in your ef dbcontext? And what is the name of your dbcontext?

Comment: dbcontext.AttendanceReports

Comment: Maybe you should show the code of that method. Did you try to call it?